# WebScarab : Getting a PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException while connecting via https

Tags: java, proxy

Hope you are doing well.I know there are many answers alike to the issue that i am going to ask but still no one seems to help.
Please help!!!

---

**Issue:-**
I am trying to connect to a secure website(HTTPS) using WebScarab, so that i can capture the traffic.Http is working fine for me.
For this i am using WebScarab as a proxy.

```
'client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("127.0.0.1", 8008);'
```

but everytime i gets an exception (

> `SunCertPathBuilderException`

) as stated above.
I have tried adding the website certificate to the Java using Keytool utility also.
I then added a proxy (reverse) entry in WebScarab (127.0.0.1 , 443) and changed the program to use it as a proxy server.

```
'client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("127.0.0.1", 443);'
```

Then i got the following exception :-

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server stbeehive.oracle.com failed to respond with a valid HTTP response.
```

I also tried creating a .p12 certificate (for the website which i want to connect to) and importing it to WebScarab.

But inspite of all these methods i am not able to get the proper response.

I am using WebScarab as a proxy for firefox to capture its traffic and it is working fine (for both http and https).

Please help me as i have run out of ideas now :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebScarab or WebScarab-NG?

Please try WebScarab "classic", rather than the -NG variant. NG was a failed experiment, and no real effort was put into validating the client-side certificate functionality.

Also, what version of Java are you using, what operating system, 32 bit or 64-bit, etc, etc

Regards,

Rogan